# How many activities is recommended for keeping in stack?

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I know how activity lifecycle works.
But i have one question. How many activities it is recommended to keeping in stack? Example i have about 6 activities. User will be navigate from first activity till the last one. The activities will go step by step from start activity till last one, and with backPress in first one again.
Here is my mapView[image]

There is only one step that i'm going from activity 3 to Activity 1.
In this case i'm using

```
finishAffinity();
```

for be sure that all stack is clean, and then i'm starting a new one Activity 1 again

Comment: Adding to below answer, the only thing you can be worried on memory is the onSaveInstanceState, so keep it a minimum, also unfinished AsyncTasks will usually crash the state of Activity. Views will be destroyed.

Answer (score 4):

From a programmer's perspective, as opposed to a UX designer's perspective, there is no recommended number of Activity to keep in the stack at one time.

Bear in mind that the Android OS can, in conditions of low memory, stop and save the instance state of the older Activities on the stack. If the user clicks the back button and reaches the older Activities their instance state is restored.

Because this is all managed for you, you do not have to worry about having a number of Activity in the stack consuming resources at one time. The most important thing here is to program the lifecycle callbacks like `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` correctly so that this management of memory is transparent to you as a programmer.

You can learn more about the stack in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack)

Comment: Android does not destroy individual activities in the backstack, only the entire stack when the task is in the background. But the docs say it could, so some future version might. The "don't keep activities" developer option causes it to behave the way the docs allow.

Comment: @TKK thanks for correcting me - I'll update the answer

Comment: Unfortunately in my project which I'm using FreshMvvm framework, whenever the stack size reaches about 20 pages(more or less) I get an OutOfMemory.

Comment: @Vahid are you sure there is no memory leak?

Comment: Hmm I can't say that's not possible.

Comment: @vahid maybe you can use LeaksCanary to find it. Or the Android monitor where it shows memory consumption

Comment: @DavidRawson Thanks, I'll take a look at that to see that possibility.